# ZipEntry to File

Tags: java, file, zip

Is there a direct way to unpack a `java.util.zip.ZipEntry` to a `File`?

I want to specify a location (like "C:\temp\myfile.java") and unpack the Entry to that location.

There is some code with streams on the net, but I would prefer a tested library function.

Comment: *"...to a `File`?"* [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is an abstract representation of a pathname. Do you mean "file" (no code markup)?

Comment: A mean, I give the function a File and it unpacks the entry to that abstract pathname.

Comment: I am sorry if this is unclear or a duplicate, but please comment instead of justing voting it down.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use ZipFile class

```
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("zipfile");
```

Get entry

```
    ZipEntry e = zf.getEntry("name");
```

Get inpustream

```
    InputStream is = zf.getInputStream(e);
```

Save bytes

```
    Files.copy(is, Paths.get("C:\\temp\\myfile.java"));
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the below code to extract the "zip file" into File's then add in the list using `ZipEntry`. Hopefully, this will help you.

```
private List<File> unzip(Resource resource) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(resource.getInputStream());
        ZipEntry entry = null;
        while((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            File file = new File(entry.getName());
            FileOutputStream  os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                os.write(c);
            }
            os.close();
            files.add(file);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error while extract the zip: "+e);
    }
    return files;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ZipInputStream` to move to the desired `ZipEntry` by iterating using the `getNextEntry()` method. Then use the `ZipInputStream.read(...)` method to read the bytes for the current `ZipEntry`. Output those bytes to a `FileOutputStream` pointing to a file of your choice.

Comment: This means: No, there is no library function?

Comment: Yes, @JFMeier yes, right you) There's much of library functions which Java don't have.