# How can I get all the directories within a jar as a List of File objects?

Tags: java, file, directory, jar, java-io

I have a jar which has a resources folder that contains a folder, let's call it `toplevel`. `toplevel` contains another folder, called `level1`. `level1` then contains a list of directories. I'd like to retrieve these directories as `java.io.File` objects, so that another function can do things with these File objects. With the below example that'd be a `List<File>` like `List{dira, dirb, dirc}` How can this be done?

```
toplevel

---level1

------dir a

------dir b

------dir c
```

Comment: A JAR file is just a ZipFile, so you could, in theory, just unzip. *"'d like to retrieve these directories as java.io.File objects"* isn't how Jar files work, as stated, they are zip files, so you need to extract the "file" from the jar or use a `OutputStream` to read it

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758105/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-within-a-jar/18758724#18758724)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, what is the path to use in here 
`jf = new JarFile(new File("dist/ResourceFolderCounter.jar"));`

where I don't have a path ending in `.jar` but rather a URI of the jar like `jar:file:....`

Comment: @MadProgrammer so you are saying it's not possible to get a List<java.io.File> objects from the jar? As in even creating a temporary folder, copying over all the contents of the jar and getting a reference to the dirs in that temp folder as a List<File> ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to extract all the files from the jar file if you want a `File` reference

Comment: You can't. A directory entry in a zip file is not a `File`. A `File` represents a file name on a file system.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest extracting matching entries from the jar file and save to a temporary location to get the java.io.File reference.

#### Option #1:

If you are reading from a file system, use ZipFile to read the file then use ZipFile.getEntry("zip-path") to get the entry and save using Files.copy

**See:** [ZipEntry to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890005/zipentry-to-file)

#### Option #2:

If you are reading from an input stream source, use ZipInputStream to read the jar file, then iterate, filter and apply action to matching entries. Each matching entry is coupled with a matching ZipInputStream and you can use those input streams to save them to a temporary location, then create the List<File> reference to hand off to another function.

I wrote a quick example in this repo:

- https://github.com/nfet/java-zip-demo/tree/main/src/main/resources

The demo essentially just reads the jar file in the resource folder and finds a single matching zip entry (META-INF/license.txt) and saves it to a file.

[image]

#### See Example Implementation in:

- https://github.com/nfet/java-zip-demo/blob/7dbdba9c47e0773f959d740d62fbb63949eaca94/src/main/java/com/example/jar/demo/ReadJarFile.java

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/nfet/27fce2870b8cd42e3337f6a21b8e9711.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help folks but after much ado, found a solution working atop this previous solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529707/9486041
to narrow down to the folders and its contents.

```
JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) folderURL.openConnection()
JarFile jar = new JarFile(new File(connection.getJarFileURL().toURI()))
Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries();
while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry file = (JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();
    if (!file.name.startsWith(path + "/")) {
        continue
    }
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/tmp" + File.separator + file.getName());
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs()
    
    InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    while (is.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
        fos.write(is.read());
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();

}
jar.close()
```